# A word to describe the desire to climb a mountain

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to find a way to describe the feeling of seeing a mountain and thinking, I want to climb to the very top of that in one word. I know it is a common feeling but there does not appear to be a succinct way to describe that emotion/sensation. I've looked in websters, OED, online and have found nothing.

Comment: Is this literally climbing a mountain, or overcoming difficulties in general?

Comment: http://explosm.net/comics/4054/

Comment: Something other than _ambition_?

Comment: “Because it’s there . . .” A challenge.

Comment: Is it just the [yearning](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/yearn) or strong desire to do anything you've just seen, or specifically to climb mountains?

Comment: Becauseitsthereism!

Comment: How about acrophilia?

Comment: I was slightly miffed to discover exelevation and exaltitude were both already taken :(

Comment: How about the desire to deep-sea dive? Or sky dive? Or write a book? Or tell you neighbors they are dumb idiots? Not every desire to do some thing has its own word.

Answer (score 3):

**mountainlust** (usually **mountain lust**)

In the first example it is a literal translation of the German; perhaps also based on

> **wanderlust**—An eager desire or fondness for wandering or travelling. OED

---

> ... did not know the names of any of the mountains in his district. He
> had to ask around for this information... The Javanese clearly lack
> what Junghuhn calls *berglust*, which can be translated as
> ***mountainlust***... which, in turn, is part of a larger codification. [E. M. Beekman; *Troubled Pleasures*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Troubled_Pleasures/8fFlAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22The%20Javanese%20clearly%20lack%20what%20Junghuhn%20calls%20berglust%20%22&dq=%22The%20Javanese%20clearly%20lack%20what%20Junghuhn%20calls%20berglust%20%22&printsec=frontcover) (1996)

> [Jon Miller; ***Mountain Lust**: The Allure of Mont Blanc*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mountain_Lust/DIwsBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=mountainlust&pg=PT1&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> Unlike other regiments, the SAS didn't grant their soldiers funds or
> time off for adventure training. It was particularly tough on Nine
> Troop guys, because they all got **mountain lust** sooner or later.
> [Andy McNab; *Seven Troop*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Seven_Troop/pX06EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=mountainlust&pg=PT253&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> **Mountain lust** gripped me, as it sometimes does when I think back on why I would spend twenty-four hours hiking up and down a rivet of
> magmic earth, one of the most-climbed, one of the most-photographed
> mountains in the world, why I would hike in the dark, through a storm,
> to sit in the cold and wait for the same light that appears everywhere
> on Earth. [C. C. Peters; *Mountain Madness*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mountain_Madness/Cd8iEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=mountainlust&pg=PA1&printsec=frontcover)

> ...have taken up cross-country skiing as a winter outlet for my
> **mountain lust**. [Stephen Smith; *Escape to the Mountain*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Escape_to_the_Mountain/VIsLoPbaspkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22mountain%20lust%22&pg=PA175&printsec=frontcover)

> Ah, the allure of switchback trails into the unknown heights. My
> **mountain lust** stirred for a second. [Lone Morch; *Seeing Red*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Seeing_Red/zH2lDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22mountain%20lust%22&pg=PT75&printsec=frontcover)

> It was particularly tough on Nine Troop guys, because they all got
> **mountain lust** sooner or later. [Andy McNab; *Seven Troop*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Seven_Troop/pX06EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22mountain%20lust%22&pg=PT253&printsec=frontcover)

> Soon the **mountain lust** will be in man's veins and the open road
> and the open sky will beckon. [*Trail and Timerline*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trail_and_Timberline/8hRBAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22soon%20the%20mountain%20lust%22)

---

> The sight of a mountain like Mount Rainier, to those of us who love
> mountains, causes a brief increase in the pulse and a sudden, quiet,
> yet involuntary intake of air through pursed lips, as though our whole
> being is saying, “Wow! Look at the beauty of that!” This physical
> reaction is usually followed immediately by the thought, “I must go
> there. A mountain lover like me has a desire for mountains that could
> perhaps be best described as “**mountain lust**.” [Frank Henninger;
> *Exploring Mount Rainier*](https://frankhenninger.com/articles/vu-magazine-article.pdf)

> In this Spot, Sadhguru sends a message from the foothills of mighty
> Annapurna, Nepal’s famed mountain range. Inspired by these snowcapped
> peaks, Sadhguru “spills” poems. “Home at Hamde,” “Annapoorna,” and
> “Mountain Lace” are sure to stir up “**mountain lust**,” as Sadhguru
> puts it. ["About **Mountain Lust**"](https://gaana.com/song/mountain-lust-sadhguru-spot-of-23-aug-2018)

> Our Company **Mountain Lust (meaning — A strong Desire for Mountains/
> Love for Mountains)**, was formed in year 2016, but registered in 2018
> as ... [moutainlust website](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mountain%20lust%22&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&sxsrf=AOaemvJf2rgi5wEDCw_yLOX8fWvKgrFBrQ:1639431627782&ei=y723YdmJL4fDytMPzbWY6A8&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiZm7re3uH0AhWHoXIEHc0aBv04ChDw0wN6BAgBEEE&biw=933&bih=447&dpr=1.5)

> Visit the top hills stations in India to discover the spellbinding
> natural beauty of the country and soothe your **mountain lust**.
> [Trinity World Holidays](https://www.trinityairtravel.com/blog/24-04-2017/Best-Hill-Stations-in-India-to-Soothe-Your-Mountain-Lust/14/)

Comment: Is this in the lexis? If not, it's non-standard and unsuitable to give on ELU. Even as an open compound, it should be in standard dictionaries if it's lexical.

Comment: mountainlust appears to be a nonce formation. Even though mountain lust isn't a single word, I thought it could be of use to the OP. An experienced user commented that a dictionary can't be expected to have every collocation. I've added several other examples.

Comment: Is it even a common collocation? Google hits seem to focus on individual repeated usages. Giving collocations when the question is a SWR is not a fitting answer; this is where I feel the 'don't make suggestions in 'comments' brigade' is too inflexible.

Comment: I offered it as an answer because I did find the one-word *mountainlust* in print. (I used Goggle Books,) // It appears to be common enough if you're looking for a word to mean "seeing a mountain and thinking, I want to climb to the very top of that" :-) I have no problem deleting the answer if you think that best.

Comment: So is 'interfrastically' and a lot of other non-lexical offerings. If we can't find it in a dictionary, I feel it should be relegated to a suggestion (with caveat) in a comment.

Comment: A comment isn't the place to link examples of usage for the OP to consider and I wouldn't want to suggest *mountain lust* without them. There are no other answers, one-word or otherwise.